# Joomla: Get base url inside article

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I would like to get the base url of my website from inside my article. Is there any way to do this either using built-in Joomla functionality or with a plugin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the JURI method to get the base URL, but you will need to add an extension that allows you to use PHP code in an article.

```
JURI::root()
```

This will return the root URL based on where Joomla is installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use base url for linking purpose then you can use index.php in place of base url.It will work fine.Because base url is also point the index.php of the website.